# React Router get result of Prompt or history.block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dialog, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm using React-Router's [Prompt](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Prompt.md) to show confirm dialog before leaving the page. They implemented Prompt using `history.block` from the [history package](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#blocking-transitions), which uses the browser's default dialog. The issue is that many browsers show a "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" option, and when user clicks on this, any action that would initiate the Prompt dialog is completely ignored (nothing happens on click).

I'm trying to implement a workaround that requires me getting the result of the Prompt, or getting the result of `history.block`. Is there a way to do an action as soon a selection has been made on the dialog created with `history.block` ?

Comment: could you use `componentWillunmount` to detect when the user is leaving the page? Not sure if that would give you the result you want, but maybe worth looking into?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. What I'm really trying to detect is when an action is made on the dialog created with history.block (user either clicks OK to leave page or Cancel). I'm more concerned with *when* the user makes the selection, not necessarily which one is selected

Comment: @OMGitzMidgar Hey man. Any chance you figured this out? :)

Answer (score 11):

You can choose to not use Prompt and use the history.block method yourself to take some relevant action like create a custom popup/modal to alert the user if he tries to go back. Don't forget to unblock it on unmount or before using any routing method.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Modal from "/location/to/modal"

function Component({ history }) {

  const [isShowModal, changeModalVisibility] = React.useState<boolean>(false)
  const unblockHandle = useRef<any>();

  useEffect(() => {
    unblockHandle.current = history.block((targetLocation: any) => {
      // take some custom action here
      // i chose to show my custom modal warning user froim going back
      // rather than relying on the browser's alert
      handleShowModal()
      return false;
    });
    return function () {
      unblockHandle.current.current && unblockHandle.current.current()
    }
  })

  function handleShowModal() {
    changeModalVisibility(true)
  }
  function onCancel() {
    changeModalVisibility(false)
  }

  function handleConfirm() {
    if (unblockHandle) {
      unblockHandle.current()
    }
    // navigate to some other page or do some routing action now
    // history.push("/any/other/path")
  }

  return (
    // some modal here
    <Modal show={isShowModal} onCancel={onCancel} onConfirm={handleConfirm} />
  );
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Could you explain what the line `unblockHandle.current.current && unblockHandle.current.current()` does? I found it hard to understand.

Comment: it just unblocks the history before unmounting the component as all side-effects need to be removed in the useEffect hook.

Comment: But what does the double `.current.current` do?

Comment: Dear, Does this solution works to prevent browser back button?

Comment: The unblockHandle is unnecessary as history.block returns a UnregisterCallback

Answer (score 0):

This is the working example for blocking navigation using `history.block` with custom modal in React Router Dom V5

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { UnregisterCallback } from "history";
...

type Prop = {
  verify?: {
    blockRoute?: (nextRoute: string) => boolean;
  }
};

...
// in the component where you want to show confirmation modal on any nav change

const history = useHistory();
const unblock = useRef<UnregisterCallback>();
const onConfirmExit = () => {
  /**
   * if user confirms to exit, we can allow the navigation
   */

  // Unblock the navigation.
  unblock?.current?.();
  // Proceed with the blocked navigation
  goBack();
};

useEffect(() => {
  /**
   * Block navigation and register a callback that
   * fires when a navigation attempt is blocked.
   */
  unblock.current = history.block(({ pathname: to }) => {
   /**
    * Simply allow the transition to pass immediately,
    * if user does not want to verify the navigate away action,
    * or if user is allowed to navigate to next route without blocking.
    */
   if (!verify || !verify.blockRoute?.(to)) return undefined;

   /**
    * Navigation was blocked! Let's show a confirmation dialog
    * so the user can decide if they actually want to navigate
    * away and discard changes they've made in the current page.
    */
   showConfirmationModal();
   // prevent navigation
   return false;
});

// just in case theres an unmount we can unblock if it exists
  return unblock.current;
}, [history]);
```